# QML type from C++ Plugin signaling only once

Tags: c++, qt, qml, qt5.5

I have a C++ plugin that watches for file changes with *QFileSystemWatcher* and connects it's *fileChanged* signal with a custom QML type slot like this:

```
//In the custom QML type constructor
QObject::connect(&this->_watcher, SIGNAL(fileChanged(QString)),
                        this, SLOT(fileChangedSlot(QString)));
```

The slot function:

```
void CustomQMLTypeClass::fileChangedSlot(QString file)
{
    Q_UNUSED(file);
    emit fileChanged();
}
```

In the QML side:

```
CustomQMLType{
    fileUri: "some/file/path/file.format"
    onFileChanged: console.log("File changed")
}
```

While running the program all goes right, but when I do, i.e.:

> echo "sth" >> some/file/path/file.format

More than once, the notification is only triggered once. Why? O.o

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently the problem is with [`QFileSystemWatcher`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5.5/qfilesystemwatcher.html), it sometimes worked and some others don't.
As I can handle the cost, my quick solution was to alter the slot:

```
void CustomQMLTypeClass::fileChangedSlot(QString &file)
{
    _watcher.removePath(file);
    _watcher.addPath(file);
    emit fileChanged();
}
```

Now it works as expected but don't know why and couldn't get to understand neither with [`QFileSystemWatcher`'s source](http://osxr.org:8080/qt/source/qtbase/src/corelib/io/qfilesystemwatcher.cpp). Finally I decided KDE's [`KDirWatch`](http://api.kde.org/frameworks-api/frameworks5-apidocs/kcoreaddons/html/classKDirWatch.html) is way better.